# Reindeer.BUTTON_LINK in Vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin8

I am trying to have button which looks like a link in Vaadin 8.2.0. I am developing in Netbeans 8.2. I found this piece of code:

```
Button btn = new Button("Click Here"); 
btn.setStyleName(Reindeer.BUTTON_LINK);
```

But, it seems that in Vaadin 8 there is not such a Reindeer class. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternatively: `ValoTheme.BUTTON_LINK`

See [Javadoc](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/themes/ValoTheme.html#BUTTON_LINK).

Answer (score 1):

BaseTheme.LINK_STYLE should work in v8